# Convert a local time to different time based on time zone - javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I understand that this question is being asked several times. But I couldn't find my code to get working anyway.

I have the following strings and I want to convert my local time to the desired time zone.

For example:

```
var localtime; // 11:30
var localtimezone; // (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
var desiredtimezone; // (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
```

This is a code I am using from this article:
[Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

## Code

```
var localtime; // 11:30
var localtimezone; // (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
var desiredtimezone; // (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)

alert(toTimeZone(localtime, desiredtimezone));

function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

Based on the above example: my local time is 11:30 and I want to convert it to the time (which should be: 1:30) based on the desiredtimezone.

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire yes i have read it but couldnt my code get to working.

Comment: @orbnexus so you must post your code

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire I have updated my ticket and added the code

Comment: Why did you add format on moment initialisation?